# Convenient way to get time of surgery in MIMIC-III

Tags: mimic-iii

In the MIMIC-III database there is a PROCEDURES_ICD that gives ICD9 codes for procedures such as surgeries that were performed on patients. The corresponding description of these codes are nice and detailed, but in the table there is no date time saying when these procedures were performed.

On the other hand, the CPTEVENTS table gives less detailed surgery descriptions, but gives the exact date time the surgery was performed.

Has anyone tried coalescing these two sources to get detailed procedure information AND datetime information? Perhaps there is a better table I should look at?

Comment: I tried the method described above, unfortunately, it doesn't work. The time stamp for the CPT codes is only set for ca. 100.000 cpt codes of which none is non is flagged as surgery by the HCUP list. Does anyone have another idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever seen that done. You could try coalescing them, making use of the HCUP flags for surgery, which indicate if a CPT code or an ICD-9 code was a surgery or not:

https://www.hcup-us.ahrq.gov/toolssoftware/surgflags/surgeryflags.jsp